# Getting HTTP 403 when trying to generate an image via form…

Tags: javascript, php, http-status-code-403

I'm having trouble with a form, getting HTTP 403 on live server but also tried the same app on other servers and it worked fine.

What I have is looking similar to this:

**PHP (used upon form submission):**

```
if(isset($_POST['send'])){  
    if(isset($_POST['data'])){
        $signBase = $_POST['data'];
        //check if signature isn't empty
        if($signBase!='none') { 
        // Data to image 
            // split the data
            $filteredData = explode(',', $signBase);
            $unencoded = base64_decode($filteredData[1]);
            $fp = fopen('filename.png', 'w');
            fwrite($fp, $unencoded);
            fclose($fp);
        }   
    }
}   
?>
```

**The form HTML and JavaScript:**

```
<form role="form" method="post" name="signature">
  <canvas id="signature-pad" class="signature-pad"></canvas>
  <input type="hidden" name="data" id="data" value="">          
  <input type="submit" id="send" name="send" value="submit">
</form>

<script>
 var signaturePad = new SignaturePad(document.getElementById('signature-pad'), {
 backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
 penColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'});
 var saveButton = document.getElementById('send');
 saveButton.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  if (!signaturePad.isEmpty()) {
  var data = signaturePad.toDataURL('image/png');
  } else {
  var data = 'none';
  }
  document.signature.data.value = data;
  document.forms["signature"].submit();
});
</script>
```

I use the hidden input to send the data and save the image generated by signature-pad but now i'm getting HTTP 403 on the server but when tested on others (including the local) it worked fine...

trying to understand why this happens, and how to fix this?

Comment: This error most likely has nothing to do with the php script itself. Maybe there are some unexpected settings in .htaccess? My only guess would be that php doesnt have permissions to write in the directory. make sure to set it to chmod 777. that shouldnt throw a 403, tho...

Comment: Tried to test with 777 permissions but it was the same 403 error, when I comment the line:  `document.signature.data.value = data;` the flow goes right but it simply doesn't work as should. any ideas?

Comment: Yes. can you check your phpinfo? Maybe your server rejects the request because it is too long. call phpinfo(); inside any php file to output the infos.

Comment: check for  'post_max_size'